# Maven Shade Plugin - Excluding some a class of mine from being modified by the relocation process

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using Maven Shade Plugin to relocate some classes of Apache.
The issue which I'm facing is that I have this string as part of my classes:

```
private static final String ORG_APACHE_HTTP_HTTP_REQUEST = "org.apache.http.HttpRequest"
```

However the Maven Shade Plugin changes it to

```
private static final String ORG_APACHE_HTTP_HTTP_REQUEST = "com.company.dependencies.org.apache.http.HttpRequest"
```

Is there a way for me to exclude my class from being modified by the maven shade plugin?

**Current config**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.apache</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>com.company.org.apache</shadedPattern>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com.company.ClassToBeExcluded</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to this:

- You have a class: com.company.ClassToBeExcluded
- This class contains a String with this value: “org.apache.http.HttpRequest”

The shade plugin will attempt to operate on both of these by (a) relocating the class and (b) updating what it presumes is a class reference (albeit embedded in a String).

To prevent the shade plugin from updating the String you have to make the relocation of `org.apache.http.HttpRequest` a no-op like so:

```
<relocation>
    <pattern>org.apache.http.HttpRequest</pattern>
    <shadedPattern>org.apache.http.HttpRequest</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

You can, if you want, relocate `com.company.ClassToBeExcluded` like so …

```
<relocation>
    <pattern>com.foo.TheClass</pattern>
    <shadedPattern>shaded.com.foo.TheClass</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

… but as long as you tell shade not to relocate `org.apache.http.HttpRequest` then `ORG_APACHE_HTTP_HTTP_REQUEST` within that class will not be updated.

Note: `org` is quite a popular domain name so you might already be relocating it, if so then just make sure that you define the no-op relocation for `org.apache.http.HttpRequest` **above** the relocation for `org`.

I have verified this by creating a class: `com.foo.TheClass` containing `private static final String ORG_APACHE_HTTP_HTTP_REQUEST = "org.apache.http.HttpRequest”`. I then ran the shade plugin against the module which contains this class and the class was relocated and `ORG_APACHE_HTTP_HTTP_REQUEST` was updated. I then added this relocation:

```
<relocation>
    <pattern>org.apache.http.HttpRequest</pattern>
    <shadedPattern>org.apache.http.HttpRequest</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

… and ran the shade plugin and this class was relocated but `ORG_APACHE_HTTP_HTTP_REQUEST` was not updated. I also removed the relocation for `com.foo.TheClass` and re ran the shade plugin and the class was not relocated and `ORG_APACHE_HTTP_HTTP_REQUEST` was not updated.

This was verified using v3.0.0 of the shade plugin.

Note: this is a bit clunky since you might **want** to relocate the class but (understandably) not want an internal class attribute to be updated. If this is an issue for you then you might want vote for this issue [MSHADE-156](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-156).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it will change the class to its original name. The issue is that I don't want it to change the *content* of the class.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: Apologies, I misinterpreted. I have now updated my answer question with a relevant solution.